# Will mapreduce use node where most of the gzip'd file is?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I'm having an HDFS cluster with some big `gzip`'d files.

I made sure all the blocks of those `gzip`'d files are on the same DataNode, by writing them to the HDFS from this data node.

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    scp file$i.gz datanode1:
    ssh datanode$i hadoop fs -put file$i.gz /data/
done
```

Now I want to run a mapreduce task on all those files.

I expect the JobTracker to put the job for processing `file1` on `datanode1`, where all the blocks are.

Indeed, if a datanode dies I will lose locality, but will it work until it dies?

If it doesn't work like that, can I write an `FileInputFormat` that would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GZip isn't a splittable compression format (well it is if you stack gzip files end to end), so i would firstly make sure the block size of your gzip files are the same / bigger than the actual file sizes.

As the gzip file isn't splittable, if you have a 1G gzip file with 256m block size, there is a chance that not all of the blocks for this file reside on the same datanode (even if you upload from one of the datanodes, there is no guarantee over time that with failures and sure, the blocks are not moved around to other nodes). In this case the job tracker will never report a local map task if any of the blocks are non-resident on the node where the task is running.

As for task assignments - if you have say 4 map slots on datanode1, but 100 files to process then the job tracker is not going to run all 100 tasks on datanode1. It will try and run a task on datanode1 if there is a free task slot on that node and a map task that has split locations on that node, but if once those 4 slots are in use, the JT will instruct other task trackers to run the jobs (if they have free slots) rather than wait to run all 100 tasks on the same node.

Yes if the datanode dies you'll most probably lost data locality if the block size is smaller than the files (for the reason i mentioned in the first sentence), but if the block size is the same or bigger than the file then you'll have data locality on any data node that has a replica of that block.

Comment: I understand it's not guaranteed, but does it even try to schedule jobs on the DataNode with most blocks?

Comment: Essentially yes, if the JT has 100 map tasks yet to run, and a TT has a spare map task slot, it will try and run a task that will be local to that TT.